# google local search or maybe some other api

Tags: google-maps, google-local-search

im trying to implement local search api, to retreive data for shops and other things from local search, but on demo it shows me 4 pages of result only and for more, it shows a link to result page, which goes to google website, i was wondering if i can pull more data as well or only limited to 4 pages only?

http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#center_localsearch

try searching for pizza.

Comment: did you ever figure this one out?

Comment: Any relation to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260399/getting-google-map-searched-location-review-and-information?

Comment: no this one is for just getting the business listings or places listings.. but other one was for complete information of that specific business/place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from the [Google AJAX Search API documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/documentation/reference.html#_property_GSearch) (at the end of the description for  `.cursor`):

> Local search supports 4 pages (or a maximum of 32 total results)

so: no, you can *not* pull more than 4 pages of results from google local search via api.